# Custom Model Binders in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is custom model binders still being used in ASP.NET MVC 5? I cannot even get it to compile. I have the following binding code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;

namespace Playground.CustomModelBinders
{
    public class CalendarModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to register it:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CalendarModelBinder),new CalendarModelBinder()); 

        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Playground.CustomModelBinders.CalendarModelBinder' to 'System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder'
```

Comment: You appear to be have the wrong `using` statements. `ModelBindingExecutionContext` is in `System.Web.ModelBinding;` The method should be `public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)`

Comment: I forgot to paste that in. Updated the original question with additional code. Still having the same issue!

Comment: Try changing using System.Web.ModelBinding; to using System.Web.Mvc; instead and implement necessary interface members.

Comment: Remove the `using System.Web.ModelBinding;` and use `public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)` You need to use `System.Web.Mvc`, not `System.Web`

Comment: Check that the `IModelBinder` interface is `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder`

Comment: follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder that is how you build a custom model binder. And as @StephenMuecke stated that is one problem of your code and other alternative is you can inherit `DefaultModelBinder` and override the `BindModel` method to complete your model binder. This way you have more control over which Model and which properties in the model you want to manipulate.

Comment: You have another issue with binder registration: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CalendarModelBinder),new CalendarModelBinder());` You need to pass the type of model that `ModelBinder` is going to be used for and not the type of model binder

Comment: Thanks @AlexArt. That fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're using a wrong namespace. `IModelBinder` should be in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

And the method should be:

```
public object BindModel(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext
)
```

You can check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

On my second check, I found out that you're making a mistake in this line:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CalendarModelBinder),new CalendarModelBinder());
```

The first parameter of `Add` method should be the type of the bound model, not the ModelBinder. It should be something like:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyCalendar),new CalendarModelBinder());
```

Comment: For some reason it seems like it belongs to both the namespaces!

Comment: According to the example in `Pro ASP.NET MVC 5`, they're using the `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: And you can see the difference in the method signature between the two namespace.

Comment: hi, if possible can you answer issue i am facing in asp mvc cache , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-caching-static-contents-gives-500-internal-server-error) is the question. Any help would be great.